# how can i put req and response from android using json?

Tags: android, json, api, google-maps, matrix

I am new to android json i want put the req and get the response from the google matrix api server in android i want send the req :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Hyderabad,Andhra%20Pradesh,India&destinations=Eluru,Andhra%20pradesh,India&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

and that url returs the output is as fallows i want extract the km value from that result. :

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Eluru, Andhra Pradesh, Inde" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, Inde" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "330 km",
                  "value" : 330316
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 heures 1 minute",
                  "value" : 18052
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How to get the distance value and print in the app console?

Answer (score 0):

In the Following shown way you can retrieve the km from your JSON Output.

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(your result);
JSONObject json;
json = jobject;

JSONArray jrowsArray = json.getJSONArray("rows");
for(int i=0;i<jrowsArray.length;i++){

JSONArray jElementsArray = jrowsArray.getJSONArray("elements");
for(int j=0;j<jElementsArray.length;j++){
JSONObject jDistance = jElementsArray.getJSONObject("distance");
String distancekm = jDistance.getString("text");
}

}
```